# How can i call MySQL custom function in django ORM?

Tags: mysql, django

i want call this function with Django ORM, not with connection.corsur()

```
CREATE FUNCTION RefreshOrderId (order_id_ INT)
RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

   DECLARE last_order_id INT;

   SELECT MAX(order_id) INTO last_order_id FROM post_order;
   UPDATE post_order SET order_id = last_order_id + 1 WHERE order_id = order_id_;

   RETURN last_order_id + 1;

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You don't CALL functions you invoke them eg select refreshorderid(parameters)

Comment: @P.Salmon i know this is my function i use refreshorderid but i want use that in ORM       `def refresh_order_id(self):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f'''SELECT RefreshOrderId({self.order_id})''')
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        return row`

Comment: Convert the function to the procedure then use CALL. Of course, you can change the data in the function , but it is illogical. And do not use intermediate variable - the interference may give duplicates.

Comment: @Akina can you explain how can i call the procedures in django ORM not with open a connection? or give me a reference.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`Func`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) expression in Django ORM which let you invoke custom MySQL functions.

So assuning that `order_id_` is a field value from the table, you would call your function like this:

```
queryset.annotate(order_id_refreshed=Func(F('field'), function='RefreshOrderId'))
```

I hope it helped.

Comment: I have this error: OperationalError: (1442, "Can't update table 'post_order' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.") –

Comment: This seems to be an error in your stored function in MySQL unrelated to Django.